# Changing a File's content does not change the file lastModified

Tags: java, scala, file

I am writing a simple test to change a `File`'s content. As you can see the printed content is what's expected. But the `lastModified()` descriptor is not modified. Eventually, what I'm just trying to get to is a `Boolean` field representing whether or not my file has changed.

I need to make my thread sleep for 1 sec to pass the test... I don't like this it's not reliable.

Error I'm getting:

```
[header1,header2, before,before]
[header1,header2, after,after]

false was not equal to true
ScalaTestFailureLocation: NonSense at (NonSense.scala:38)
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

Code Snippet below:

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, Paths}

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class NonSense extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  val classLoader: ClassLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
  val testAclsPath: Path = Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("file/test.csv").getPath)

  def withTempConfigFile(block: (Path) => Unit) {
    val tempDir: Path = Files.createTempDirectory("test")
    val tempCsv = new File(tempDir.toFile, "test.csv")
    val path = tempCsv.toPath.toAbsolutePath
    Files.copy(testAclsPath, path)
    block(path)
  }


  "changing a file" should "change last modified timestamp" in {
    withTempConfigFile { (path) =>
        // refresh and get current Acls
        val lastModified = path.toFile.lastModified
        // read CSV
        val file = path.toFile
        val lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-8")
        System.out.println(lines)
        // delete the last line
        val deletedLine = lines.remove(lines.size() - 1)
        // add a line
        lines.add("after,after")
        // write to file
        // Thread.sleep(10) doesn't change anything, but Thread.sleep(1000) does
        FileUtils.writeLines(path.toFile, "UTF-8", lines, false)
        val linesChanged = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-8")
        System.out.println(linesChanged)
        // assert the obvious - not working
        path.toFile.lastModified() > lastModified shouldBe true
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: The granularity of last modified timestamps depend on the OS and the platform library. It can be as bad as 2s. What OS and filesystem do you run it on?

Comment: Mac OS X. I'm trying to get this test to reliably pass on any OS and any fs obviously. Is there a way to force some sort of OS Sync?

Comment: Removing the test would be most reliable, no OS/filesystem guarantees that modifications always change lastmodified. HFS+ seems to have a resolution of 1s, which means if you modify more often you won't see a change. It's generally a bad idea to base any decisions on the change of that timestamp (not only fort his reason)

Comment: @eckes the test is part of making sure that if file changes then my code does something. I've just extracted the part that makes everything fail... So to prove that my code works I can't really do without this piece

Comment: I would read the file content and check it contains what you expect.

Comment: it's a bit pricey if the file is big. `lastModified` as metadata is what I would believe would be here to prevent my from making such expensive calls

Comment: I don't see any value in testing if a file write changes the file change time, but if you think it adds benefit to your test, sleeping for 2s after initially creating the file (or possibly modifying the last modified further back into the past) will allow you to see the time to change.

Comment: If you really really to test it you should at least close and open the file again.

Comment: BTW: modifying a file is not Crash safe, maybe it would be best to write to a different file anyway, then you can check the file existence and size. And if you do not want to verify the content of the file I would also not read it and print it.